# Why we multiply probabilities with support to obtain Q-values in Distributional C51 algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, probability-distribution

In 'Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-On' book and chapter about Distributional C51 algorithm I'm reading, that to obtain Q-values from the distribution I need to calculate the weighted sum of the normalized distribution and atom's values.

Why I have to multiply that distribution with support? How does it work and what happening there?